# Why do objects at high velocity partially pass through static physics bodies?

Tags: scenekit

I am currently making a game using SceneKit, the physics bodies are acting as expected **except** when the **dynamic** body (the ball) is moving at high velocity. Part of its physics body will actually cross the **static** physics body of my wall.

Here are how I have both the static and dynamic physics bodies set up.

[image: Static Physics]

[image: Dynamic Physics]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because collision detection is happening per frame, and your object was already partially through the rigid body when collision detection occurred.

You can try increasing `continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold` to increase calculation resolution at the cost of performance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/3013743-continuouscollisiondetectionthre